# Display PopMenu with java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with popapMenu with java swing can you help me 
there is my code

```
package com.bar.menu;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PopMenuSample extends JFrame {

public PopMenuSample() {
    super("Pop menu exemple");
    this.setSize(600, 400);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = (JPanel) getContentPane();
    // the content of the window
    JScrollPane LeftjScrollPane = new JScrollPane(new JTree());
    LeftjScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 0));

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane rightjScrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, 
    LeftjScrollPane, rightjScrollPane);
    panel.add(splitPane);

    JPopupMenu popupMenu = this.createPopupMenu();
    textArea.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
            if (event.isPopupTrigger()) {
                popupMenu.show(event.getComponent(), event.getX(), 
                  event.getY());
            }
        }
    });
}

private JPopupMenu createPopupMenu() {
    JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();

    JMenuItem menuNew = new JMenuItem("New File");
    popupMenu.add(menuNew);
    return popupMenu;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
    PopMenuSample menuSample = new PopMenuSample();
    menuSample.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

this exemple is very easy (a window is contains two zones on the left is the Jtree() and on the right is textArea in this place i want to activate my problem when is of the right mouse i want to display **New File**) but i can't to show the popmenu **New File** in the textArea by the left boton of my mouse

I used java 8

Can you help me and thanks :)

Comment: `isPopupTrigger` reacts to right mouse button and not left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
```

You are only checking the mousePressed event.

The popup trigger can be different for different LAF's.

You also need to check the `mouseReleased` event.

See the section from the Swing tutorial on [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) for more information.

Comment: the problem i follow an exemple and he used

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)

Comment: @BMW83, Use the Swing tutorial as the starting point for examples. Keep a link to the tutorial handy for all Swing basics.